# Test routing contstraints via TestHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, mvccontrib-testhelper

I have the next routing.

```
routes.MapRoute("Companies", "Companies/{companyId}",
    new { controller = "Company", action = "Details" },
    new { companyId = @"\d+" });
```

Here is test which tests it.

```
"~/Companies/7".ShouldMapTo<CompanyController>(action => action.Details(7));
```

Now I want to test constraints. So url "~/Companies/df" shouldn't be mapped to the controller.

Does anyone know how to test it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using MvcContrib TestHelper to assert that an inbound route should not be mapped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007331/using-mvccontrib-testhelper-to-assert-that-an-inbound-route-should-not-be-mapped)

Answer (score 0):

```
"~/Companies/df".ShouldBeIgnored();
```